# How to change position of unity launcher in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How can I change the position of unity launcher?

Comment: already answered on Ask Ubuntu - in short - you can't.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher

Comment: This might help although it's slightly dated. It describes an alternative to the Unity Launcher: http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/blog/how-to-move-unity-launcher-ubuntu-1110.html

Answer (score -1):

```
$ gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
```